# Horizontal and vertical scroll bar if the content overflows the specified width and height in div

Tags: html, css

```css
#myleft {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

#myRight {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
}

.displayBox {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="myLeft">
    <h4>Left Content</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="myRight">
    <div class="displayBox">
      <p>Display the first content on BOX 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="displayBox">
      <p>Display the first content on BOX 2. The content might overflow if it exceeds the height of 60px otherwise its perfectly fine.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="displayBox">
      <p>Display the first content on BOX 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="displayBox">
      <p>Display the first content on BOX 4 and horizontal scroll bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

There might be three or more **div** inside **myRight** div. I want the all the divs on the same row without overflowing to the next row with horizontal scroll. For content overflow, I have specified each div with height of 60px and overflow:auto which gives me vertical scroll bar. Similarly, I want horizontal scroll if there are more than 3 divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `float`, you could use `display: flex`.

`display: flex` aligns `block` children side-by-side (similar to `float`). Adding `flex: 0 0 auto;` to these children stops them from wrapping.

To display the horizontal scrollbar, you can use `overflow-x: auto;`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

#myLeft {
  width: 20%;
}

#myRight {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.displayBox {
  width: calc(100% / 3); /* to achieve perfect thirds */
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="myLeft">
    <h4>Left Content</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="myRight">
    <div class="displayBox">
      <p>Display the first content on BOX 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="displayBox">
      <p>Display the first content on BOX 2. The content might overflow if it exceeds the height of 60px otherwise its perfectly fine.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="displayBox">
      <p>Display the first content on BOX 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="displayBox">
      <p>Display the first content on BOX 4 and horizontal scroll bar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```